# How to set RecycleView onClickListener()?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

> Has anyone using RecyclerView found a way to set an onClickListener to
>   items in the RecyclerView? I thought of setting a listener to each of
>   the layouts for each item but that seems a little too much hassle I'm
>   sure there is a way for the RecyclerView to listen for the onClick
>   event but I can't quite figure it out.

ViewHolder.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    View mView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDetails(Context ctx, String title, String desc, String image) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "Cairo.ttf");
        Typeface typeface1;
        typeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "semibold.ttf");
        TextView txt_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        ImageView imageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.image_card);
        TextView txt_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
        txt_title.setText(title);
        txt_desc.setText(desc);
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageView);
        txt_title.setTypeface(typeface1);
        txt_desc.setTypeface(typeface);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want click on whole item just do it like this.

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecysclerViewClick(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecysclerViewClick.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                       //Your Code here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // do whatever
                    }
                })
        );
```

But if you want click on specific button, textView or image setClicklistener after initialising them in onBindViewHolder

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```